# xarray resample daily min, max and mean temperatures to hourly with daily temperature profile

Tags: python-xarray

Given a dataset with daily `tasmax` and `tasmin` dataarrays, what would be the most efficient/performant way create an hourly `temperature` dataarray such that each day follows a predefined temperature profile (e.g. sinusoidal with `tasmin` at 05:00, `tasmax` at 15:00).

Could this be constructed lazily in such a way that e.g. computing the 99th percentile hourly temperature doesn't require explicitly loading into memory the entire hourly time series (which might be over 100 years for a whole GCM).